# Migrating from Trac to Redmine on another computer

Tags: migration, trac, redmine

Is it possible to migrate a Trac database to Redmine if the two systems are in different machines any other way than by copying Trac to the other machine? Migration within the same box is easy: http://www.redmine.org/wiki/redmine/RedmineMigrate, but since the migration requires access to Trac files, I can't see how this could be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no experience migrating Trac to Redmine, but I do see one solution.

It's a bit out there, but:

Archive the trac directory on the first system, then move it to the new system and extract it somewhere. Then go through the migration procedure and see if it works.

If you are using a database system other sqlite and it asks you for connection details, fill out the details as if you were connecting to it externally (don't use localhost for the host)

Example:

```
    Trac directory []: /path/to/extracted/trac
    Trac database adapter (sqlite, sqlite3, mysql, postgresql) [sqlite]: mysql
    Trac database host [localhost]: oldserver.example.com
    Trac database port [3306]:
    Trac database name []: trac_db
    Trac database schema [public]:
    Trac database username []: trac_db_username
    Trac database password []: trac_db_password
    Database encoding [UTF-8]:
    Target project identifier []: myproject
```

Again, this probably won't work, but it's worth a try.

Comment: Yeah, copying the database was what I suggested already, I guess this is the best way then.

Comment: Sorry, didn't even read the part where you said that. Hope you figured this out.

Comment: I've successfully copied a trac environment to another computer & imported it there

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using sqlite/sqlite3 here's the solution

The migration script looks for db/trac.db file in the trac directory you specify, so copy over your trac.db file from computer source to computer target and place it in a dir which matched this structure /somewhere/trac/tracprojectname/db/trac.db . Once you start running the migration script, you will be asked for trac project directory, then give /somewhere/trac/tracprojectname , the script will automatically pick the trac.db

I know, The question is old but thought this would help folks in the future.
Hope this helps.

/pnut